# Pandas: Datetime Improperly selecting day as month from date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with some datetime data in a dataframe. It's in a format day/month/year Ex:

```
Date
----------------
27/06/2021 00:00
27/06/2021 00:00
30/06/2021 00:00
30/06/2021 00:00
30/06/2021 00:00
18/06/2021 00:00
26/06/2021 00:00
28/06/2021 00:00
28/06/2021 00:00
27/06/2021 00:00
28/06/2021 00:00
30/06/2021 00:00
12/06/2021 00:00
28/06/2021 00:00
```

I want to extract the month and year, so I converted the column to datetime using `data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`

However, this is resulting in improper classification of what is the month and what is the day.  When the dates above are converted to datetime, they end up like:

```
Date
-----------
2021-06-27
2021-06-27
2021-06-30
2021-06-30
2021-06-30
2021-06-18
2021-06-26
2021-06-28
2021-06-28
2021-06-27
2021-06-28
2021-06-30
2021-12-06
2021-06-28
```

All of these dates should have 06 for June as the month. But row 13 has incorrectly assigned 12 as the month, which is leading to incorrect results when I use groupby later. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
pd.to_datetime(data['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

since the day comes obviously first in your data but pandas assumes month first by default.

[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) - "*dayfirst  :  bool, default False*"

Note: evaluation of day first / last is not strict, i.e. it is evaluated line by line - which is why you get such mixed results but no error.

Comment: ugh so simple, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If extracting month and year, did you try?

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```